# Parse exception in test environment, while in Android environment works fine

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, date, testing

I have a very simple instruction in Android:

`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ").parse("2019-07-24T21:27:09+02:00")`

The same instruction, when runs on a real device, generates the right output: a Date object that can be represented by `Wed Jul 24 21:27:09 GMT+02:00 2019`

However when I use the exact same instruction in a unit test (with junit), it gives me 
`java.text.ParseException`.

I can make it work removing the last `:`  (like this, "2019-07-24T21:27:09+0200"), but I am wondering why. I understand they use different JVM, but the Android APIs used should be the same.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I have reproduced: on my desktop Java 11, your formatter objects to the colon in the offset (between `+02` and `00`). Also [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone) say that the RFC 822 time zone should be without colon. And I tend to agree with you: in the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#timezone) I also find nothing indicating that the colon should be allowed, so it may be a bug in the Android implementation. I bet they are not going to fix it.

Comment: Indeed. I think that if they really fix it, they can create problems to all those apps running under the assumption that colon is allowed. So maybe it is better that they don't, in a way maintaining retro-buggability XD
Thank you btw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes. Never use `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-07-24T21:27:09+02:00" )
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/WXGHBc).

## *java.time*

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

These *java.time* classes are built into Java 8 and later, and in Android 26 and later. For Java 6 & 7, see the back-port in [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), further adapted for early Android in [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The `java.util.Date` class is replaced by `java.time.Instant`, both representing a moment in UTC. Your input has an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) other than zero hours-minutes-seconds, so use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class.

Your input is in standard ISO 8601 format. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-07-24T21:27:09+02:00" ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/WXGHBc).

> odt.toString(): 2019-07-24T21:27:09+02:00

To see the same moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), [extract](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toInstant()) a [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). The `Z` on the end of the ISO 8601 compliant string means UTC, pronounced “Zulu”.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2019-07-24T19:27:09Z

### Implementations vary

> I can make it work removing the last : (like this, "2019-07-24T21:27:09+0200"), but I am wondering why. I understand they use different JVM, but the Android APIs used should be the same.

(a) The behavior of `SimpleDateFormat` & `Date` is moot, as you should no longer be using those classes. They really are that bad.

(b) In any complicated framework, you may see such subtle variations between implementations, especially when built by different teams. The specifications of the legacy date-time classes do not cover such minute details as the optional colon on an offset. Such is life.

I expect you will see far fewer discrepancies in behaviors with *java.time* and the *ThreeTen-Backport*, as they were both led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne. I do not know about the Android implementation of *java.time* bundled with Android 26 and later, but I've not heard of any differences yet.

So for this, and *many* other reasons, I strongly recommend going the *java.time* route.

Comment: You are absolutely right! We regret the decision of using Date and Calendar, but it was made because of the interaction with other systems.

Comment: @GVillani82 To interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert between the legacy and modern classes. See the new `to…`/`from…` methods added to the old classes. For, `Calendar`, see the subclass `GregorianCalendar`, with its modern counterpart being `ZonedDateTime`. For `java.util.Date`, the replacement is `Instant`. For `java.sql.Date`, `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of some Java classes on Android are different from Oracle's JDK. This is likely due to the recent lawsuits against Google. Therefore, some Java APIs (mostly internationalization and ... date formatting) might behave differently. If the documentation of the class does not state that this is a valid format, you may file a bug.

Comment: Seems more likely that it's simply a different implementation being (unadvisedly) more lenient.